# How to unit test behaviour subject .value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm relatively new to Angular and I'm trying to get my code to pass a unit test, It's currently failing with this error.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

Here's my simple method, currently want to set visible to true if a company user has a driving license, and false if they don't. I don't think the unit test code is of any value since none of it works, but I've tried methods like mockServices and using fake data/return values

```
hasLicense() {
  this.licenseService.getLicences(
    this.companyService.selectedCompany.value.companyId, 
    this.companyService.selectedCompany.value.userId
  ).subscribe(l => {
    if(l.driver) {
      this.visible = true;
    } else {
      this.visible = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not test the value of the subject, it is an implementation detail. You need to test what the consumer of your class will see, in this case the `visible` property.

Comment: I think the issue I have is that this is just a small snippet of code from a product I'm working on, I singled out my section of the code thinking that's the issue but when I recreated my own project using my code it worked fine. So some sort of interaction between my code and the product is the issue. I'll mark this as correct because you are telling me to test the correct thing. Thanks